# Wrap a synchronous method into an async one which can be 'waited' upon

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-phone-8

I have a synchronous call:

```
_context.User.Where((u) => (u.UserID == twitterId && u.Type == UserType.Show)).SingleOrDefault();
```

That I need to wrap into an async one which I can wait on using the `await` keyword.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: [Relevant blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to wrap your sync call using `Task.Run` method.

```
var user = await Task.Run(() => 
   _context.User
           .Where(u => u.UserID == twitterId && u.Type == UserType.Show)
           .SingleOrDefault());
```

Keep in mind that EntityFramework in version 6.0 will have async interfaces, so you would no longer need to use this code.

Answer (score 3):

QueryableExtensions, added in EF6, make this a breeze:

```
await _context.User.SingleOrDefaultAsync(u => 
    u.UserID == twitterId 
    && u.Type == UserType.Show);
```

Don't forget to reference `System.Data.Entity` in the EntityFramework.dll