# Create async method using sync long-running tasks

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, task

Maybe this is a duplicate, but I haven't seen anything similar, or not googled so much... I'm pretty new on async pattern...

Imagine that you have a long running (and thread-blocking) processing task, bound to a DLL which you don't have code access. like this one:

```
void DoSomeLongRunningTask(out int taskProgress);
```

I need this inside an async method on an ASP.NET MVC 4 Controller. The taskProgress out parameter will feed a progressbar-like component.

How could I enclose that synchronous method on an async method?
Could you point me some direction on how do I accomplish that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try: `await Task.Run`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023333/wrap-a-synchronous-method-into-an-async-one-which-can-be-waited-upon

Comment: Thank you for answering @mafafu. But this way I could not update my progress bar through ajax, because the controller remains locked until the end of the running task

Answer (score 3):

If you need to dispatch a long running synchronous task asynchronously, and you have no access to the DLL dispatching the method to make it truely async, you can use `Task.Run` or in this case `Task.Factory.Startnew` to deploy it on a ThreadPool thread.

```
var myTask = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomeLongRunningTask(out taskProgress), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

Using `Task.Factory.Startnew` with `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` is to signal the `TaskScheduler` that we will need a new dedicated Thread for the work done so we dont cause starvation to the `ThreadPool`

`DoSomeLongRunningTask` returns a `Task` in this case, since the return type is `void`, which will be completed in the future when the method finishes.

If you had access to that method, i would suggest you look at `IProgress<T>`, which exposes a simple Progress method which with you can update your UI.

[Here is an example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis.) in case you want to implement progress next time, and you do have control over the async method.

Comment: Thank you for answering @Yuval. But since calling the method with await will block the "ActionResult" return, how could I update my progress bar with the "out int taskProgress" return parameter?

Comment: Do you control the `DoSomeLongRunningTask` implementation?

Comment: unfortunately no. The only thing I know, is that it does a lot of calculations over a datatable and reports progress through the "out" parameter. Actually, this DLL is used with a Desktop Application inside a thread. The thread updates a progress bar through BeginInvoke/Action statements.

Comment: Then your `out` param is the only way. For future use, if you need to implement progress yourself, look into `IProgress<T>`